# Modify indexes in python script using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a Python script which reads data from a database into a list and fills a template. The database structure changed so now I have to add 2 to all indexes. Is there a way to do such thing using notepad++?

What I have is something like:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = %s",id)
row = cursor.fetchone()
nameSpace = {'valone':str(row[1]),'valtwo':str(row[2]),'valthree':str(row[3]),} #and so on
```

And I need it to be:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = %s",id)
row = cursor.fetchone()
nameSpace = {'valone':str(row[3]),'valtwo':str(row[4]),'valthree':str(row[5]),} #and so on
```

There's over a hundred variables, so I don't want to do it manually.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Can you set `row = row[2:]`?

Comment: You could probably use regex search and replace in notepad++. Also this is not a python question unless you are trying to solve it **using python**

Comment: you can use "sed" if you are using linux os.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat You're right

Comment: Ir you want to use python, assign the text in curly brackets to a string variable. Then use  re.findall to find all numbers. Convert them to integers and then iterate over the list substituting each one with i+2.

Comment: Can all your indexes be matched with `\[[0-9]+\]`? Or `\w+\[[0-9]+\]`?

Comment: Or even easier split this text with comma, iterate over the list finding number and replacing the number with i+ 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple regex like `\w+\[([0-9]+)]` and use a PythonScript to process these matches, incrementing the number inside Group 1.

- Install [PythonScript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0)
- Go to *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *New Script*
- Create a new `increment_numbers_2up.py` script
- Add this contents:

---

```
def increment_2_up(match):
    return '%s%s]'%(match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2))+2))

editor.rereplace(r'(\w+\[)([0-9]+)]', increment_2_up)
```

---

Now, run the script from *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *Scripts* -> *increment_numbers_2up*

I got this result: `nameSpace = {'valone':str(row[3]),'valtwo':str(row[4]),'valthree':str(row[5]),} #and so on`

**Pattern details**:

- `(\w+\[)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word chars (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and a `[`
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ digits
- `]` - a literal closing `]` bracket.

The Python code here - `str(int(match.group(2))+2)` - parses the digits captured into Group 2 with `int(match.group(2)`, then adds `2`, and casts the value to a string with `str()`.

Comment: That's what I needed! I had to change the \w for a literal, though, there were other lists in the code.
Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, the pattern can be customized to match what you need. Glad it worked for you.