# Notepad++ add Suffix after each 5 lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file contains a list of usernames (+100,000 lines), I'd like to add a Suffix after each 5 lines.

Example:

```
Username1
Username2
Username3
Username4
Username5 SUFFIX HERE!
Username6
Username7
Username8
Username9
Username10 SUFFIX HERE!
Username11
Username12
Username13
Username14
Username15 SUFFIX here!
Username16
... etc.
```

I've tried to use regex to search for `^(.+)$` then `\1 suffixtext!` with failed attempt. it change all the lines. while i just need each 5 lines.

I want to also add a random number after the suffix.

Thank you,
regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^.*(?:\R.*){4}
```

And replace with `$& SUFFIX 0`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\R.*){4}` - exactly 4 occurrences of a line break (any style, `\R`) followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`).

The replacement contains a backreference to the whole match (`$&`) and then a number.

See the screenshot with settings:

[image]

To later increment the numbers after `SUFFIX`, use a Python Script

```
cnt = 0
def incrementnum(match):
    global cnt
    cnt = cnt + 1
    return "{0}{1}".format(match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2))+cnt))
editor.rereplace(r'(SUFFIX )(\d+)$', incrementnum)
```

Just follow [these instructions to use it in your NPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664254/modify-indexes-in-python-script-using-notepad/38664672#38664672).

Comment: @Wkitor Works perfectly, thank you, now is it possible to add a random number after the suffix?, example suffix 1, suffix 2, suffix 3, etc?

Comment: stribzew I've tried that trick already it doesn't work. I will be really happy if you can find a solution for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you did not ask for that in the question. It is still possible to do in Notepad++, but that requires using a Python script. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664254/modify-indexes-in-python-script-using-notepad/38664672#38664672) explaining how this can be done.

Comment: stribizew Works perfectly. Thanks a million. you are the greatest.